# How do I change the size of the menus in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-xp

This is the weirdest thing:
For some reason, when I'm running VS 2008 in XP, and I use the 'Advanced Appearance settings' control panel to change the Size of menu items in all applications, Visual Studio 2008 is unaffected by the change.  (That's Control Panel -> Display -> Appearance tab -> Advanced -> select 'Menu' from the item drop-down, and change the Font size)
Anyone else noticed this?  Is anyone aware of a fix?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the settings from *Advanced Appearance Settings* don't affect VS2008, but you can change the menu item settings (and many more) from within VS2008.

From VS2008, go to *Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors*.

In the *Show settings for:* dropdown, select *Environment Font*. Make the changes here as you see fit.

Learn more about customizing the Visual Studio development environment here...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hthab0h8.aspx